Why on fresh install of Angular 17 "npm test" starts the browser 3 times, crashes when I close the window and I need Ctrl+C to stop npm command?
This is the 1st time I'm doing Angular tests and I am a bit confused of the way it works.
Karma starts with chrome, but when I close the window, the browser starts again 3 times in total.
Is it possible to just start it once and get my terminal back once the browser is closed? Otherwise, what is the way to start tests?
I do this in a brand new fresh install:
ng new my-app
ng test

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
13 04 2024 08:34:36.638:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
13 04 2024 08:34:36.648:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.3 server started at http://localhost:9876/
13 04 2024 08:34:36.648:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
13 04 2024 08:34:36.651:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
13 04 2024 08:34:37.526:INFO [Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket 0PHdt_fcK_BO2szUAAAB with id 75531898
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.113 secs / 0.101 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.113 secs / 0.101 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.113 secs / 0.101 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
13 04 2024 08:34:46.729:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed.
    [20219:20219:0413/083437.333482:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[20261:20261:0413/083438.893641:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[20261:20261:0413/083441.099878:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
[20261:20261:0413/083441.107439:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!

13 04 2024 08:34:46.729:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
13 04 2024 08:34:46.729:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [20219:20219:0413/083437.333482:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[20261:20261:0413/083438.893641:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!
[20261:20261:0413/083441.099878:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 2 times!
[20261:20261:0413/083441.107439:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 3 times!

13 04 2024 08:34:46.760:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
13 04 2024 08:34:47.649:INFO [Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket REfkwyHpFp9GiKGIAAAD with id 75531898
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.14 secs / 0.124 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.14 secs / 0.124 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.14 secs / 0.124 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
13 04 2024 08:34:50.740:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed.
    [20378:20378:0413/083447.474174:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[20420:20420:0413/083448.983396:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!

13 04 2024 08:34:50.740:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
13 04 2024 08:34:50.740:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [20378:20378:0413/083447.474174:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented
[20420:20420:0413/083448.983396:ERROR:gl_surface_presentation_helper.cc(260)] GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 1 times!

13 04 2024 08:34:50.759:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
13 04 2024 08:34:51.648:INFO [Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket IIrf0gQVfAEpbds1AAAF with id 75531898
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.123 secs / 0.111 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.123 secs / 0.111 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.123 secs / 0.111 secs)
Chrome 123.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
13 04 2024 08:34:53.880:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed.
    [20538:20538:0413/083451.450316:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented

13 04 2024 08:34:53.880:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
13 04 2024 08:34:53.880:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr: [20538:20538:0413/083451.450316:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.GetActive: object_path= /org/freedesktop/ScreenSaver: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: This method is not implemented

13 04 2024 08:34:53.899:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (crashed). Giving up.
^C^C

ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 17.3.4
Node: 20.12.2
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 17.3.4
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1703.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.3.4
@angular-devkit/core            17.3.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.3.4
@schematics/angular             17.3.4
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.4.5
zone.js                         0.14.4

cat package.json 
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.3.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.2.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}

